# iOS/Objective-C equivalent of Android's AsyncTask

Tags: android, ios, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm familiar with using `AsyncTask` in Android: create a subclass, call `execute` on an instance of the subclass and `onPostExecute` is called on the UI thread or main thread. **What's the equivalent in iOS?**

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Answer to Original Question:

Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) offers a mechanism to perform tasks in the background, though it works in a structurally different way than AsyncTask. To perform something asynchronously, you just need to create a queue (like a thread) and then pass a block to `dispatch_async()` to be performed in the background. I find it neater than AsyncTask, as there is no subclassing involved; it is more or less plug-and-play wherever you have code you'd like to execute in the background. An example:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourdomain.yourappname", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //code to be executed in the background
});
```

### Other Points:

#### 1) Callbacks

If you want to perform a task in the background and update the UI (or do something on another thread) when the background task is done, you can simply nest the dispatch calls:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourdomain.yourappname", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //code to be executed in the background
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //code to be executed on the main thread when background task is finished
    });
});
```

#### 2) Global Queues

When creating a queue, you can also use the `dispatch_get_global_queue()` function to get a global dispatch queue with a certain priority (such as `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`). These queues are universally accessible and are useful when you want to assign multiple tasks to the same thread/queue. Note that memory is managed for you completely by iOS.

#### 3) Memory

There is sometimes some confusion regarding memory management and dispatch queues because they have their own `dispatch_retain`/`dispatch_release` functions. However, rest assured that they are treated as Objective-C objects by ARC, so you don't need to worry about calling these functions. Referencing [rob mayoff's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619055/791018) regarding GCD and ARC, you can see the documentation describe GCD queues' equivalence with Objective-C objects:

```
* By default, libSystem objects such as GCD and XPC objects are declared as
* Objective-C types when building with an Objective-C compiler. This allows
* them to participate in ARC, in RR management by the Blocks runtime and in
* leaks checking by the static analyzer, and enables them to be added to Cocoa
* collections.
*
* NOTE: this requires explicit cancellation of dispatch sources and xpc
*       connections whose handler blocks capture the source/connection object,
*       resp. ensuring that such captures do not form retain cycles (e.g. by
*       declaring the source as __weak).
*
* To opt-out of this default behavior, add -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 to your
* compiler flags.
*
* This mode requires a platform with the modern Objective-C runtime, the
* Objective-C GC compiler option to be disabled, and at least a Mac OS X 10.8
* or iOS 6.0 deployment target.
```

#### 4) Multiple Tasks/Blocks

I'll add that GCD has a grouping interface supports synchronizing multiple asynchronous blocks if a task cannot continue until multiple asynchronous activities have completed. Jörn Eyrich and ɲeuroburɳ provide a generous explanation of this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909629/waiting-until-two-async-blocks-are-executed-before-starting-another-block). If you need this functionality, I would highly recommend taking a few minutes to read both of their answers closely and understand the differences between them.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079) has a wealth of information on the topic if you are so inclined.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a callback that executes on the main thread?

Comment: Doesn't `queue` need to be destroyed with `dispatch_release`?

Comment: As of iOS 6.0 (and OS X 10.8), ARC will manage Grand Central Dispatch objects as they are treated as Objective-C object. So, if you deployment target is < iOS 6.0 or OS X 10.8, then yes, `queue` must be explicitly released. Otherwise, no, ARC will handle it.

Answer (score 17):

There are no classes for that in iOS but you can simulate it using queues.
You can call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Your code to execute in background...
});
```

for async tasks and inside your async code call next queue to do something in the view...:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Your code to execute on UIthread (main thread)
});
```

Then, using this two queues you can create a asyncTask class, add this class to your project to implement them:

---

```
//
//  AsyncTask.h
//
//  Created by Mansour Boutarbouch Mhaimeur on 25/10/13.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AsyncTask : NSObject

- (void) executeParameters: (NSArray *) params;
- (void) preExecute;
- (NSInteger) doInBackground: (NSArray *) parameters;
- (void) postExecute: (NSInteger) result;
@end
```

---

```
//
//  AsyncTask.m
//
//  Created by Mansour Boutarbouch Mhaimeur on 25/10/13.
//

#import "AsyncTask.h"

@implementation AsyncTask

- (void) executeParameters: (NSArray *) params{
    [self preExecute];
    __block NSInteger result;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        result = [self doInBackground:params];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self postExecute:result];
        });
    });
}

- (void) preExecute{
    //Method to override
    //Run on main thread (UIThread)
}

- (NSInteger) doInBackground: (NSArray *) parameters{
    //Method to override
    //Run on async thread (Background)
    return 0;
}

- (void) postExecute: (NSInteger) result{
    //Method to override
    //Run on main thread (UIThread)
}

@end
```

---

This is an example that I am using in a project:

---

```
#import "AsyncTask.h"
#import "Chat.h"

@interface SendChatTask : AsyncTask{
    NSArray * chatsNotSent;
}

@end
```

---

```
#import "SendChatTask.h"

@implementation SendChatTask

- (void) preExecute{
    //Method to override
}

- (NSInteger) doInBackground: (NSArray *) parameters{
    //Method to override
    NSString *sendChatsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",HOST, NAMESPACE,URL_SEND_CHAT];
    chatsNotSent = [parameters objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *response;
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    //...
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[ChatJSONParser wrapChatArray: chatsNotSent] options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [params setObject:JSONString forKey:@"chats"];

    response = [HTTPClient executePOST:sendChatsURL parameters:params];

    if([respuesta isEqualToString:@"true"]){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

- (void) postExecute: (NSInteger) result{
    //Method to override
    if (result == 1) {
        for (Chat *chat in chatsNotSent) {
            chat.state = STATE_NOT_SENT;
            [chat save];
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDelegate refreshChat];
        }
    } else {

    }
}

@end
```

---

And the following call:

```
[[[SendChatTask alloc] init] executeParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: chatsNotSent, nil]];
```

You can add a `publishProgress()` update method and respective... I don't use it for the moment because I call my async task in background services.

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: probably more descriptive than necessary... the bad of copy/paste

Answer (score 5):

if your targeting earlier iOS Version (than iOS 4 for Grand Central Dispatch) you could use the NSObject performSelector methods

- **Execute on Background** Thread [performSelectorInBackground:withObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground%3awithObject%3a)
- And **execute on MainThread** [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a)

This is an example:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(executeInBackground) withObject:nil];


-(void) executeInBackground
{
    NSLog(@"executeInBackground");

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(executeOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void) executeOnMainThread
{
    NSLog(@"executeOnMainThread");
}
```

Comment: Less than 5% of iOS users are <4.0

Comment: i totally agree, that optimizing for low iOS Version is probably not always worth it. 
But i rather prefer the ObjectiveC-API of performSelector than the API in C of Grand Central Dispatch. the iOS 2+ part is just a bonus feature.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I actually like the C-style syntax better because you don't need to create a new method for each task, and sharing variables is easier (NSObject methods can only take one parameter, and passing an array of assorted objects is messy)

Comment: @JeanLuc What are the performance implications between this solution and the one from @Rickay?

Comment: Honestly I can't say. It's possible that at runtime, they both do pretty much the same thing, but the syntax is just different. I don't really know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653522/grand-central-dispatch-vs-nsthread might give you some information

Comment: @Rickay: i agree performOnMainThread/performOnBackgroundThread methods with Blocks would be nice. concerning sharing variables i would use either properties inside the object itself or create a class with values you want to pass.

Comment: @SundayMonday i don't think, there is a performance difference. under the hood, they are doing the same thing: changing threads. 
if you can't decide which solution to use in your implement: flip a coin.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3

In Android when I wanted to run a task on a background thread and then update the UI when it finished, I used `AsyncTask` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647881/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation/25647882#25647882)). Now when I am making iOS versions of my apps, I use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) (GCD) to do the same thing. Here is how it is done with Swift:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    // code to be run on a background task

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        // code to be run on the main thread after the background task is finished
    }
}
```

## Notes

- [Grand Central Dispatch Tutorial for Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a c# Xamarin.iOS version with PusblishProgress:

```
internal abstract class AsyncTask : NSObject
{
    protected abstract nint DoInBackground(NSArray parameters);

    protected abstract void PostExecute(nint result);

    public void ExecuteParameters(NSArray @params)
    {
        this.PreExecute();

        DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.Default).DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            //We're on a Background thread
            var result = this.DoInBackground(@params);
            DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => {
                // We're on the main thread
                this.PostExecute(result);
            });
        });

    }

    protected abstract void PreExecute();

    protected void PublishProgress(NSArray parameters)
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            // We're on the main thread
            this.OnProgressUpdate(parameters);
        });
    }

    protected abstract void OnProgressUpdate(NSArray parameters);
}
```

And implementation:

```
internal class MyAsyncTask : AsyncTask
{
    protected override void OnProgressUpdate(NSArray parameters)
    {
        // This runs on the UI Thread
    }

    protected override nint DoInBackground(NSArray parameters)
    {
        // Do some background work
        // ....
        var progress = NSArray.FromObjects(1, "Done step 1");
        PublishProgress(progress);

        return 0;
     }

     protected override void PostExecute(nint result)
     {
         // This runs on the UI Thread

     }

     protected override void PreExecute()
     {
        // This runs on the UI Thread

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `GCD`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61102990/4770877) as a variant of `AsyncTask`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49338894/4770877)

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    //background thread
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //main thread
    }
}
```