# Waiting until two async blocks are executed before starting another block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

When using GCD, we want to wait until two async blocks are executed and done before moving on to the next steps of execution. What is the best way to do that?

We tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block1
});


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block2
});

// wait until both the block1 and block2 are done before start block3
// how to do that?

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block3
});
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43022956/1966109) for Swift 5 that offers up to six different ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Use dispatch groups: see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) for an example, "Waiting on Groups of Queued Tasks" in the "Dispatch Queues" chapter of Apple's iOS Developer Library's Concurrency Programming Guide

Your example could look something like this:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block1
    NSLog(@"Block1");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
    NSLog(@"Block1 End");
});


dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block2
    NSLog(@"Block2");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:8.0];
    NSLog(@"Block2 End");
});

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block3
    NSLog(@"Block3");
});

// only for non-ARC projects, handled automatically in ARC-enabled projects.
dispatch_release(group);
```

and could produce output like this:

```
2012-08-11 16:10:18.049 Dispatch[11858:1e03] Block1
2012-08-11 16:10:18.052 Dispatch[11858:1d03] Block2
2012-08-11 16:10:23.051 Dispatch[11858:1e03] Block1 End
2012-08-11 16:10:26.053 Dispatch[11858:1d03] Block2 End
2012-08-11 16:10:26.054 Dispatch[11858:1d03] Block3
```

Comment: Cool. will the async tasks/blocks, once associated with the group, be executed sequentially or concurrently? I mean, assume that block1 and block2 are associated with a group now, will block2 wait until block1 is done before it can start executing?

Comment: That's up to you. `dispatch_group_async` is just like `dispatch_async`with a group parameter added. So if you use different queues for block1 and block2 or schedule them on the same concurrent queue, they can run concurrently; if you schedule them on the same serial queue, they'll run serially. It's no different from scheduling the blocks without groups.

Comment: Does this also apply to executing web service post?

Comment: Do you notice that the time is not equal to the sleep time set in your block? why it would be like this?

Comment: In ARC just remove dispatch_release(group);

Comment: what will happen if I does not write this line     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:8.0];

Comment: AND how does it distinguish that this is block 2 and the other one is block 1? how can we prioritize them?

Comment: `ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'`

Answer (score 286):

Expanding on Jörn Eyrich answer (upvote his answer if you upvote this one), if you do not have control over the `dispatch_async` calls for your blocks, as might be the case for async completion blocks, you can use the GCD groups using `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave` directly.

In this example, we're pretending `computeInBackground` is something we cannot change (imagine it is a delegate callback, NSURLConnection completionHandler, or whatever), and thus we don't have access to the dispatch calls.

```
// create a group
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

// pair a dispatch_group_enter for each dispatch_group_leave
dispatch_group_enter(group);     // pair 1 enter
[self computeInBackground:1 completion:^{
    NSLog(@"1 done");
    dispatch_group_leave(group); // pair 1 leave
}];

// again... (and again...)
dispatch_group_enter(group);     // pair 2 enter
[self computeInBackground:2 completion:^{
    NSLog(@"2 done");
    dispatch_group_leave(group); // pair 2 leave
}];

// Next, setup the code to execute after all the paired enter/leave calls.
//
// Option 1: Get a notification on a block that will be scheduled on the specified queue:
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"finally!");
});

// Option 2: Block an wait for the calls to complete in code already running
// (as cbartel points out, be careful with running this on the main/UI queue!):
//
// dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // blocks current thread
// NSLog(@"finally!");
```

In this example, computeInBackground:completion: is implemented as:

```
- (void)computeInBackground:(int)no completion:(void (^)(void))block {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"%d starting", no);
        sleep(no*2);
        block();
    });
}
```

Output (with timestamps from a run):

```
12:57:02.574  2 starting
12:57:02.574  1 starting
12:57:04.590  1 done
12:57:06.590  2 done
12:57:06.591  finally!
```

Comment: @ɲeuroburɳ The above code waits on the main thread.  I believe this will block the main thread and cause the UI to be unresponsive until the whole group is complete.  I recommend moving the wait to a background thread. For example, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)

Comment: @cbartel, good catch!  I've updated the example code to reflect your comment.  Many times you need the callback to be on the main queue--in that case though the `dispatch_queue_notify` is likely better (unless the blocking time is guaranteed to be short).

Comment: Where can I release the group ( i.e. dispatch_release(group) )?  I'm unsure if it's safe to release in dispatch_group_notify.  But since that's the code that is run after the group is complete, I'm unsure where to release.

Comment: If you are using ARC then you do not need to call dispatch_release: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues

Comment: If not using ARC, then "it is valid to release the group after setting a notification block" https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_group_notify.3.html

Comment: Nice post which further explains that: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/

Answer (score 126):

With Swift 5.1, *Grand Central Dispatch* offers many ways to solve your problem. According to your needs, you may choose one of the **seven patterns** shown in the following Playground snippets.

---

#### #1. Using [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup), `DispatchGroup`'s [`notify(qos:flags:queue:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/2016066-notify) and [`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)'s [`async(group:qos:flags:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016098-async)

The Apple Developer Concurrency Programming Guide [states about `DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25):

> Dispatch groups are a way to block a thread until one or more tasks finish executing. You can use this behavior in places where you cannot make progress until all of the specified tasks are complete. For example, after dispatching several tasks to compute some data, you might use a group to wait on those tasks and then process the results when they are done.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.app.queue", attributes: .concurrent)
let group = DispatchGroup()

queue.async(group: group) {
    print("#1 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("#1 finished")
}

queue.async(group: group) {
    print("#2 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("#2 finished")
}

group.notify(queue: queue) {
    print("#3 finished")
}

/*
 prints:
 #1 started
 #2 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 */
```

---

#### #2. Using [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup), `DispatchGroup`'s [`wait()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/2016090-wait), `DispatchGroup`'s [`enter()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/1452803-enter) and `DispatchGroup`'s [`leave()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/1452872-leave)

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.app.queue", attributes: .concurrent)
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
queue.async {
    print("#1 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("#1 finished")
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
queue.async {
    print("#2 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("#2 finished")
    group.leave()
}

queue.async {
    group.wait()
    print("#3 finished")
}

/*
 prints:
 #1 started
 #2 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 */
```

Note that you can also mix `DispatchGroup` `wait()` with `DispatchQueue` `async(group:qos:flags:execute:)` or mix `DispatchGroup` `enter()` and `DispatchGroup` `leave()` with `DispatchGroup` `notify(qos:flags:queue:execute:)`.

---

#### #3. Using [`Dispatch​Work​Item​Flags`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitemflags) [`barrier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitemflags/1780674-barrier) and [`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)'s [`async(group:qos:flags:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016098-async)

[Grand Central Dispatch Tutorial for Swift 4: Part 1/2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2) article from Raywenderlich.com gives a definition for *barriers*:

> Dispatch barriers are a group of functions acting as a serial-style bottleneck when working with concurrent queues. When you submit a `DispatchWorkItem` to a dispatch queue you can set flags to indicate that it should be the only item executed on the specified queue for that particular time. This means that all items submitted to the queue prior to the dispatch barrier must complete before the `DispatchWorkItem` will execute.

Usage:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.app.queue", attributes: .concurrent)

queue.async {
    print("#1 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("#1 finished")
}

queue.async {
    print("#2 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("#2 finished")
}

queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
    print("#3 finished")
}

/*
 prints:
 #1 started
 #2 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 */
```

---

#### #4. Using [`DispatchWorkItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem), [`Dispatch​Work​Item​Flags`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitemflags)'s [`barrier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitemflags/1780674-barrier) and [`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)'s [`async(execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016103-async)

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.app.queue", attributes: .concurrent)

queue.async {
    print("#1 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("#1 finished")
}

queue.async {
    print("#2 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("#2 finished")
}

let dispatchWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem(qos: .default, flags: .barrier) {
    print("#3 finished")
}

queue.async(execute: dispatchWorkItem)

/*
 prints:
 #1 started
 #2 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 */
```

---

#### #5. Using [`DispatchSemaphore`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore), `DispatchSemaphore`'s [`wait()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore/2016071-wait) and `DispatchSemaphore`'s [`signal()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore/1452919-signal)

Soroush Khanlou wrote the following lines in [The GCD Handbook](http://khanlou.com/2016/04/the-GCD-handbook/) blog post:

> Using a semaphore, we can block a thread for an arbitrary amount of time, until a signal from another thread is sent. Semaphores, like the rest of GCD, are thread-safe, and they can be triggered from anywhere. Semaphores can be used when there’s an asynchronous API that you need to make synchronous, but you can’t modify it.

Apple Developer API Reference also gives the following discussion for `DispatchSemaphore` [`init(value:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore/1452955-init) initializer:

> Passing zero for the value is useful for when two threads need to reconcile the completion of a particular event. Passing a value greater than zero is useful for managing a finite pool of resources, where the pool size is equal to the value.

Usage:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.app.queue", attributes: .concurrent)
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

queue.async {
    print("#1 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("#1 finished")
    semaphore.signal()
}

queue.async {
    print("#2 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("#2 finished")
    semaphore.signal()
}

queue.async {
    semaphore.wait()
    semaphore.wait()    
    print("#3 finished")
}

/*
 prints:
 #1 started
 #2 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 */
```

---

#### #6. Using [`OperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) and `Operation`'s [`addDependency(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1412859-adddependency)

The Apple Developer API Reference states about `Operation​Queue`:

> Operation queues use the `libdispatch` library (also known as Grand Central Dispatch) to initiate the execution of their operations.

Usage:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

let blockOne = BlockOperation {
    print("#1 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("#1 finished")
}

let blockTwo = BlockOperation {
    print("#2 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("#2 finished")
}

let blockThree = BlockOperation {
    print("#3 finished")
}

blockThree.addDependency(blockOne)
blockThree.addDependency(blockTwo)

operationQueue.addOperations([blockThree, blockTwo, blockOne], waitUntilFinished: false)

/*
 prints:
 #1 started
 #2 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 or
 #2 started
 #1 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 */
```

---

#### #7. Using [`OperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) and `OperationQueue`'s [`addBarrierBlock(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/3172534-addbarrierblock) (requires iOS 13)

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

let blockOne = BlockOperation {
    print("#1 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("#1 finished")
}

let blockTwo = BlockOperation {
    print("#2 started")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("#2 finished")
}

operationQueue.addOperations([blockTwo, blockOne], waitUntilFinished: false)
operationQueue.addBarrierBlock {
    print("#3 finished")
}

/*
 prints:
 #1 started
 #2 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 or
 #2 started
 #1 started
 #2 finished
 #1 finished
 #3 finished
 */
```

Comment: Is there a solution for async calls without using group.enter() and group.leave() for each (and without semaphores)? Like If I need to wait for an async request to a server, then after that wait for a second async request and so on.
I've read this article https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/asynchronous-operations/ but I don's see a simple usage of it comparing to BlockOperation

Answer (score 57):

Another GCD alternative is a barrier:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.app.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 
    NSLog(@"start one!\n");  
    sleep(4);  
    NSLog(@"end one!\n");
});

dispatch_async(queue, ^{  
    NSLog(@"start two!\n");  
    sleep(2);  
    NSLog(@"end two!\n"); 
});

dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{  
    NSLog(@"Hi, I'm the final block!\n");  
});
```

Just create a concurrent queue, dispatch your two blocks, and then dispatch the final block with barrier, which will make it wait for the other two to finish.

Comment: Is there any problem if I did not use     sleep(4);

Comment: No, of course, there is no problem with that. In fact, you practically never want to `sleep()`! I only added those `sleep()` calls for pedagogic reasons, to make the blocks run long enough so that you can see that they run concurrently. In this trivial example, in the absence of `sleep()`, these two blocks may run so quickly that the dispatched block might start and finish before you have a chance to empirically observe the concurrent execution. But don’t `sleep()` in your own code.

Answer (score 40):

I know you asked about GCD, but if you wanted, `NSOperationQueue` also handles this sort of stuff really gracefully, e.g.:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Starting 3");
}];

NSOperation *operation;

operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Starting 1");
    sleep(7);
    NSLog(@"Finishing 1");
}];

[completionOperation addDependency:operation];
[queue addOperation:operation];

operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Starting 2");
    sleep(5);
    NSLog(@"Finishing 2");
}];

[completionOperation addDependency:operation];
[queue addOperation:operation];

[queue addOperation:completionOperation];
```

Comment: This is fine when the code inside of your NSBlockOperation is synchronous. But what if it's not, and you want to trigger completion when your async operation is done?

Comment: @GregMaletic In that case, I make a `NSOperation` subclass that is concurrent and set `isFinished` when the asynchronous process completes. Then the dependencies work fine.

Comment: @GregMaletic See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429011/use-of-delegates-in-nsoperation/18431755#18431755 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426855/how-do-i-start-an-asychronous-nsurlconnection-inside-an-nsoperation/17427268#17427268 for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I decided to go with GCD plus a dispatch_semaphore to notify when the async operations terminate.

Comment: @GregMaletic Yeah, you can use that, too (as long as `dispatch_semaphore_wait` is not taking place on the main queue and as long as your signals and waits are balanced). As long as your don't block the main queue, a semaphore approach is fine, if you don't need the flexibility of operations (e.g. having the ability to cancel them, ability to control degree of concurrency, etc).

Comment: @Rob:  Can you please elaborate or update your answer with example of running the code above with asynchronous blocks?  I would like to wait for operation1 & operation2 (both are async.) before executing operation 3.  Thanks

Comment: @Rob  I posted a question so you can get credit.  Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919771/ios-nsoperationqueue-with-async-blocks

Comment: @user1107173 You either should (a) use semaphores; (b) use the above NSOperation approach, but use synchronous renditions of your operations; or (c) wrap your asynchronous operation in a concurrent `NSOperation` that will only signal `isFinished` when the asynchronous request is done. See my answer posted at that other question.

Comment: And how do you make the priority between task one and two?

Comment: @Reza.Ab - If you need task one to finish before task two starts, add a dependency between those tasks. Or if the queue is always only performing one task at a time, make it a serial queue by setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to `1`. You can set priority of operations, too, both the `qualityOfService` and `queuePriority`, but these have a far more subtle impact on task priority than the dependencies and/or degree of queue concurrency.

Comment: I see, and yes my tasks should be serial and be done on main thread so I guess Ill do what you said, Thank you @Rob

Comment: Whether the tasks should be serial and whether you do it on the main thread are two different questions. You can have serial background queues, too (e.g. an operation queue with a `maxConcurrentQueueCount` of `1`). And you presumably had a reason to move these tasks off of the main thread to start with...

Answer (score 4):

Answers above are all cool, but they all missed one thing. group executes tasks(blocks) in the thread where it entered when you use `dispatch_group_enter`/`dispatch_group_leave`.

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
      dispatch_queue_t demoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.demo.group", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
      dispatch_async(demoQueue, ^{
        dispatch_group_t demoGroup = dispatch_group_create();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          dispatch_group_enter(demoGroup);
          [self testMethod:i
                     block:^{
                       dispatch_group_leave(demoGroup);
                     }];
        }

        dispatch_group_notify(demoGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          NSLog(@"All group tasks are done!");
        });
      });
    }

    - (void)testMethod:(NSInteger)index block:(void(^)(void))completeBlock {
      NSLog(@"Group task started...%ld", index);
      NSLog(@"Current thread is %@ thread", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"main" : @"not main");
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.f];

      if(completeBlock) {
        completeBlock();
      }
    }
```

this runs in the created concurrent queue `demoQueue`. If i dont create any queue, it runs in **main thread**.

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    dispatch_group_t demoGroup = dispatch_group_create();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      dispatch_group_enter(demoGroup);
      [self testMethod:i
                 block:^{
                   dispatch_group_leave(demoGroup);
                 }];
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(demoGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSLog(@"All group tasks are done!");
    });
    }

    - (void)testMethod:(NSInteger)index block:(void(^)(void))completeBlock {
      NSLog(@"Group task started...%ld", index);
      NSLog(@"Current thread is %@ thread", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"main" : @"not main");
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.f];

      if(completeBlock) {
        completeBlock();
      }
    }
```

and there's a third way to make tasks executed in another thread:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
      dispatch_queue_t demoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.demo.group", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
      //  dispatch_async(demoQueue, ^{
      __weak ViewController* weakSelf = self;
      dispatch_group_t demoGroup = dispatch_group_create();
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(demoGroup);
        dispatch_async(demoQueue, ^{
          [weakSelf testMethod:i
                         block:^{
                           dispatch_group_leave(demoGroup);
                         }];
        });
      }

      dispatch_group_notify(demoGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"All group tasks are done!");
      });
      //  });
    }
```

Of course, as mentioned you can use `dispatch_group_async` to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The first answer is essentially correct, but if you want the very simplest way to accomplish the desired result, here's a stand-alone code example demonstrating how to do it with a semaphore (which is also how dispatch groups work behind the scenes, JFYI):

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        dispatch_queue_t myQ = dispatch_queue_create("my.conQ", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
        dispatch_semaphore_t mySem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        dispatch_async(myQ, ^{ printf("Hi I'm block one!\n"); sleep(2); dispatch_semaphore_signal(mySem);});
        dispatch_async(myQ, ^{ printf("Hi I'm block two!\n"); sleep(4); dispatch_semaphore_signal(mySem);});
        dispatch_async(myQ, ^{ dispatch_semaphore_wait(mySem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); printf("Hi, I'm the final block!\n"); });
        dispatch_main();
}
```

Comment: Two observations: 1. You're missing a `dispatch_semaphore_wait`. You have two signals, so you need two waits. As is, your "completion" block will start as soon as the first block signals the semaphore, but before the other block finishes; 2. Given this was an iOS question, I'd discourage the use of `dispatch_main`.

Comment: I agree with Rob.  This is not a valid solution.  The `dispatch_semaphore_wait` will unblock as soon as either of the `dispatch_semaphore_signal` methods are called.  The reason this may appear to work is that the `printf` for blocks 'one' and 'two' occur immediately, and the `printf` for the 'finally' occurs after a wait--thus after the block one has slept for 2 seconds.  If you put the printf after the `sleep` calls, you'll get the output for 'one', then 2 seconds later for 'finally', then 2 seconds later for 'two'.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2 example:**

```
let group = DispatchGroup.group(count: 2)
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
     self.renderingLine = false
     // all groups are done
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.renderTargetNode(floorPosition: targetPosition, animated: closedContour) {
        group.leave()
        // first done
    }
    self.renderCenterLine(position: targetPosition, animated: closedContour) {
        group.leave()
        // second done
    }
 }
```

Comment: `group.leave()` caused crash

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer in swift:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.async(group: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default), execute: {
    // block1
    print("Block1")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5.0)
    print("Block1 End")
})


group.async(group: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default), execute: {
    // block2
    print("Block2")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 8.0)
    print("Block2 End")
})

dispatch_group_notify(group, DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default), {
    // block3
    print("Block3")
})

// only for non-ARC projects, handled automatically in ARC-enabled projects.
dispatch_release(group)
```

Answer (score -4):

Not to say other answers are not great for certain circumstances, but this is one snippet I always user from Google:

```
- (void)runSigninThenInvokeSelector:(SEL)signInDoneSel {


    if (signInDoneSel) {
        [self performSelector:signInDoneSel];
    }

}
```