# In iOS, How Can I Execute Certain Code Only After All Parse.com Find/Save Operations Complete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I'm working in Xcode 4.6.2, trying to develop an iPhone app.

I've been struggling with this on-and-off for weeks now in my spare time, and I am at the point of considering giving up development and never trying to create a mobile app again. I am so demoralized by what should be an easy thing to do...

All I'm trying to do is:

1. use Parse.com's API to "findObjects"/"findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" & "save"/"saveInBackgroundWithBlock" to get & save data; and then
2. after all such operations are complete, do stuff after that (with full knowledge of the results of all the Parse operations executed).

For example, I would like to save some objects to Parse via a for-loop, and then after saving them all, know how many were successful, erred, etc. so that I can display those numbers on the screen.

Also for example, I'd like to do the same thing with finding objects in Parse.com, and then after I'm done finding stuff, calculate and display how many items were found, how many duplicates, etc. (again, on the iPhone screen)

Why is this so difficult?!

I've tried using the multitude of Grand Central Dispatch examples out there, such as "dispatch_async" and "dispatch_group_async" + "dispatch_group_notify". I've tried GCD with the "WithBlock" Parse.com methods as well as the non-blocked versions.

Sample Problem #1: spinner hides before all items are retrieved from Parse.com (I want the hideSpinnerDownloadingMovies method - and anything else in there - to execute only after fetchDataWithBlock and all findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock inside fetchedDataWithBlock are totally complete!)

```
        [self showSpinnerDownloadingMovies];
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.task", NULL);
        dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [self fetchDataWithBlock];
            dispatch_async(main, ^{
                [self hideSpinnerDownloadingMovies];
            });
        });
```

[source] http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html

The Log reads like this:

```
2013-06-09 18:17:09.159 TestApp[4425:4503] Epic
2013-06-09 18:17:09.160 TestApp[4425:4503] 104
2013-06-09 18:17:09.236 TestApp[4425:4503] Star Trek Into Darkness
2013-06-09 18:17:09.237 TestApp[4425:4503] 129
2013-06-09 18:17:09.341 TestApp[4425:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 18:17:09.385 TestApp[4425:4503] Fast & Furious 6
2013-06-09 18:17:09.386 TestApp[4425:4503] 130
2013-06-09 18:17:09.484 TestApp[4425:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 18:17:09.545 TestApp[4425:4503] After Earth
2013-06-09 18:17:09.545 TestApp[4425:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 18:17:09.546 TestApp[4425:4503] 100
2013-06-09 18:17:09.634 TestApp[4425:4503] The Hangover Part III
2013-06-09 18:17:09.635 TestApp[4425:4503] 100
2013-06-09 18:17:09.636 TestApp[4425:c07] hiding spinner...
2013-06-09 18:17:09.742 TestApp[4425:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 18:17:09.968 TestApp[4425:c07] movie added!
```

(see how the hideSpinnerDownloadingMovies method is executing before fetchDataWithBlock is finished?)

Sample Problem #2: same as above, order of the code is not guaranteed (hideSpinnerDownloadingMovies, etc. executes while some objects are still being found/processed in fetchDataWithBlock).

```
    [self showSpinnerDownloadingMovies];
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self fetchDataWithBlock];
    });
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self hideSpinnerDownloadingMovies];
    });
```

[source] [Waiting until two async blocks are executed before starting another block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909629/waiting-until-two-async-blocks-are-executed-before-starting-another-block)

The Log reads like this:

```
2013-06-09 23:09:04.291 TestApp[4983:4903] Epic
2013-06-09 23:09:04.292 TestApp[4983:4903] 104
2013-06-09 23:09:04.365 TestApp[4983:4903] Star Trek Into Darkness
2013-06-09 23:09:04.366 TestApp[4983:4903] 129
2013-06-09 23:09:04.544 TestApp[4983:4903] Fast & Furious 6
2013-06-09 23:09:04.545 TestApp[4983:4903] 130
2013-06-09 23:09:04.696 TestApp[4983:4903] After Earth
2013-06-09 23:09:04.697 TestApp[4983:4903] 100
2013-06-09 23:09:04.797 TestApp[4983:4903] The Hangover Part III
2013-06-09 23:09:04.797 TestApp[4983:4903] 100
2013-06-09 23:09:04.798 TestApp[4983:4903] hiding spinner...
2013-06-09 23:09:05.049 TestApp[4983:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 23:09:05.051 TestApp[4983:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 23:09:05.053 TestApp[4983:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 23:09:05.070 TestApp[4983:c07] movie added!
2013-06-09 23:09:05.287 TestApp[4983:c07] movie added!
```

(again, the hideSpinnerDownloadingMovies method is executing before fetchDataWithBlock is finished - I just ran this one again and it looks a lot like the log above, with 2 "movie added!" after "hiding spinner...")

Here are a few other pages I've read and tried:
(I wish I could post the links, but it appears I need 10 reputation to do so...apparently, you aren't getting those links - FYI, they come from fieryrobot.com and some other stackoverflow.com pages)

I just want to be able to find/save stuff such that the UI doesn't freeze (so, in the background) and be able to do some things only after all find/save operations are completed (display stats based on the operations, etc.). I don't think I'm asking for too much?

I believe the answer lies in using the correct combination of Parse.com's APIs (either blocked or non-blocked) along with Apple's Grand Central Dispatch. But that magical, mystical combination eludes me.

Bottom line: Can anyone provide a code sample that executes all Parse.com find/save operations before executing another, separate piece of code?

This must be possible, otherwise how could you ever report accurate stats about operations, etc. back to the user? How are others accomplishing this goal?

I'm at wits-end...

Comment: Had to comment right after reading the beginning.  Don't give up - once you solve the problem it will be so satisfying.  EDIT: upon reading, have you looked at exactly what the code does when you do dispatch_async?  Cutting and pasting examples is often dangerous without knowing fully what's happening, especially with async/event driven code

Comment: Thank you for your support. The "fetchDataWithBlock" method gets JSON data containing movie information and then loops through that data - calling out to Parse.com's API "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" method of their PFQuery object. Within the "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" method is where I can check whether anything was returned, erred, etc. And that's the reason for my question - I want to wait until all separate calls to this method are completed so that I can evaluate all the results at once (were all movies found, did some err, etc.?)

Comment: can you explain the nature of the `fetchDataWithBlock` method as in do you have access to this method's code ?

Comment: hey user ... it couldn't be easier to do this using Parse.  Do you still need the answer?  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this so difficult?!

Because the right level of abstraction here is `NSOperation` which adds helpful features, such as **dependency**, to GCD. See [my answer in *Best way to manage many block calls*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226713/115200).