# Multiple calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler with GCD in iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, grand-central-dispatch

I need to do multiple request for a `MKDirections` (10) and I want to make faster my `iOS7` App.
After 10 `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler`, I want to update user interface.
I try with async calls with `GCD`.

My problem is that with `GCD` I don't understand how to wait the end of all `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler` before to update user interface.

This is my code:

```
dispatch_group_t taskGroup =  dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue =  dispatch_get_main_queue();

dispatch_group_async(taskGroup, mainQueue, ^{
    [directions1 calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {...}];
});

.........

dispatch_group_async(taskGroup, mainQueue, ^{
    [directions10 calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {...}];
});

/* Update UI */
dispatch_group_notify(taskGroup, mainQueue, ^{

    /* Do some processing here and UI Update */

});
```

The problem is that the UI is updated before of the end of all `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler`!

Why?
Which is the problem in my code?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You can refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909629/waiting-until-two-async-blocks-are-executed-before-starting-another-block

Comment: Please can you explain to me? I don't understand.

Comment: At a simple level you could keep an int reference to the number of updates received, and then fire your update method once it reaches 10 ?

Comment: Please can you give me an example?