# at point dispatch_group_async considers the task done when it is executing async task with callbacks

Tags: ios

- I make three `async` requests together all of  which I need to wait for before moving forward.
- I have read following to synchronize async requests

[Waiting until two async blocks are executed before starting another block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909629/waiting-until-two-async-blocks-are-executed-before-starting-another-block)

```
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^ {
...
});
```

runs task *async*. But my **task itself** is `async` and it calls callback handlers.

So, when will **my task** be declared **done** in the context of `dispatch_group_async`?

Would it be called done when my callbacks have been executed?

If you could provide sequence of events that will happen till the point my task will be declared done will be very helpful

Comment: What do you mean by "my task" - The async tasks in the dispatch_group?  The task that is dispatching the tasks on the dispatch_group?

Comment: The block that will be executed in dispatch_group_async will have async n/w requests

Comment: So once the block queues the async network requests that task will then continue to release the dispatch_group, so from the point of view of the dispatch_group (and the execution of a `dispatch_group_notify` or `dispatch_group_wait`) the tasks will be complete even though the network activity is still continuing in the background.

Comment: Yes, that would be one way of meeting your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dispatch an asynchronous task, say "task B", inside a `dispatch_group_async`, say "Task A" then Task A will be considered complete as soon as the end of the Task A block is reached even though Task B may still be executing.

So, given

```
dispatch_async_group(group,queue, ^{ 
      [someAsyncTask B];
});

dispatch_async_group(group,queue, ^{ 
      [someAsyncTask C];
});

dispatch_async_group(group,queue, ^{ 
      [someAsyncTask D];
});

dispatch_group_wait(group,10000);
```

The `dispatch_group_wait` will return as soon as the final `dispatch_async_group` block finishes executing even though tasks B/C/D may still be running.

If you use synchronous dispatch for tasks B/C/D then your dispatch group will be considered complete after B,C & D finish.