# Adding a "Final" NSOperation to a Queue with Undetermined Number of Operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm using AFNetworking as my network stack to communicate with a web service and populate a local data store. During synchronization runs, I have an array of API endpoints to run through, and when that run is complete, I add a final operation, which takes the resulting JSON to fill up the database.

The problem I'm having is that the result of some of those JSON-fetching operations requires me to call other endpoints, and now I don't know when I should add that "Final" operation.

The way I have things working now, I have a series of primary operations, and then add the "final" operation. During that time, the primaries have returned and caused me to create secondary operations, like so:

```
* Primary Fetch Operation A
* Primary Fetch Operation B
* Final Operation
* Secondary Fetch Operation B1
```

I need to figure out how to ensure that "Final Operation" is always going to run last.

One thing I've tried is adding an observer to the operation queue's `operationCount` property, but it seems that it can run down to 0 before a secondary operation is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe the observer won't work, AFNetworking invokes callbacks from the `completionBlock` of `NSOperation` and this means that the operation is already finished and removed from the queue, which explains why you have reached a `operationCount` of 0 before submit the secondary operation.

You could use a `dispatch_group_t` to accomplish this, before scheduling an operation (primary or secondary) you enter the group (`dispatch_group_enter`) and then when the operation completes you leave the group (`dispatch_group_leave`). If the finished operation requires a secondary operation before leaving the group follow the same pattern, enter the group again and schedule the secondary operation. Finally you will be notified (`dispatch_group_notify`) when all the operations have completed making the perfect time to schedule the final operation.

Comment: Yes! Lovely answer, thank you. I found some more information about a couple implementations in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909629/waiting-until-two-async-blocks-are-executed-before-starting-another-block