# Multiple async requests completion handler in Swift with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm building my app with Swift and I'm using Alamofire for my web requests. I need to perform 4 requests at the same time and then run a function only when information is downloaded. How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: The 4 requests need to be done at the same time? Or one depend on the other and need to requested sequentially?

Comment: at the same time. I know how to do this sequentially, thank you

Comment: This is a little confusing. Do you actually need these operations to happens at the exact same instant or can they be delayed by milliseconds. Same instant, I have no clue. Milliseconds already happens with async functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatch_group_async` and `dispatch_group_notify`. Create group of requests with `dispatch_group_async` and `dispatch_group_notify` will notify you once all the requests are complete.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to have a variable you would lock (or not if it's an atomic variable) you would increment after each request is executed. If it reaches 4 once you increment it, execute your function.

Comment: grand central dispatch has great facilities for these types of operations as well

Comment: I managed this by myself and I'm using `NSTimer()` to check if variable is equal to 4. Can I do this without timer? Thank you!

Comment: Actually I think I found exactly what you need (and what Dan is speaking of). Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11909880/4021216