# Swift / How to use dispatch_group with multiple called web service?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `dispatch_group` to call Firebase requesting functions and get notified once the request is complete to be able to work with the result then. In this scenario I've just put a print statement.

```
func loadStuff() {
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
        myFirebaseFunction() {
             dispatch_group_leave(group)
        }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("done")
    }
}

func myFirebaseFunction(completionHandler: () -> ()) {

    let usersRef = firebase.child("likes")
    usersRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

             if snapshot.exists() {
                   let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date",ascending: false)])

                   for item in sorted {

                       dict.append(item as! NSDictionary)
                   }
            }
            completionHandler()
   })   
}
```

This code is working fine. **The problem is** that, during runtime, data will be added into the Firebase Database. That is why I have to use `observeEventType` instead of `observeSingleEventOfType`.

This means there is an observer during runtime and in case data has been added to the database, the block within `myFirebaseFunction` will be called again.

Once this happens, the app crashes because `dispatch_group_leave(group)` has been called without `dispatch_group_enter(group)`. As long as I got this right.

```
dispatch_group_enter(group)
    myFirebaseFunction() {
         dispatch_group_leave(group)      // crash here
    }
```

If I change it to `observeSingleEventOfType`, no crash occurs, but new added Data to Firebase will not be observed.

What's the best practice to use `dispatch_group` with multiple run Web Services? Or what do I have to do to fix my issue? Help is very appreciated.

PS Currently I'm using Swift 2.3, but an upgrade to Swift 3 is planned, so it would be very awesome to receive an answer capable for both.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The Problem

As you stated, calls to `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave` must be balanced. Here, you are unable to balance them because the function that performs the actual real-time fetching only calls leave.

### Method 1 - All calls on the group

If you take no issue with `myFirebaseFunction` always performing its work on that dispatch group, then you could put both enter and leave inside there, perhaps with a beginHandler and completionHandler:

```
func loadStuff() {
    myFirebaseFunction(beginHandler: {
        dispatch_group_enter(group)
        dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("done")
        }
    }, completionHandler: { dispatch_group_leave(group) })

}

func myFirebaseFunction(beginHandler: () -> (), completionHandler: () -> ()) {        

    let usersRef = firebase.child("likes")
    usersRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        beginHandler()
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date",ascending: false)])

            for item in sorted {

                dict.append(item as! NSDictionary)
            }
        }
        completionHandler()
   })   
}
```

Here, the completion handler would still be set to `dispatch_group_leave` by `loadStuff`, but there is also a begin handler that would call `dispatch_group_enter` and also `dispatch_group_notify`. The reason notify would need to be called in begin is that we need to ensure that we have already entered the group before we call notify or the notify block will execute immediately if the group is empty.

The block you pass to `dispatch_group_notify` will only be called exactly once, even if blocks are performed on the group after notify has been called. Because of this, it might be safe for each automatic call to `observeEventType` to happen on the group. Then anytime outside of these functions that you need to wait for a load to finish, you can just call notify.

**Edit:** Because notify is called each time `beginHandler` is called, this method would actually result in the notify block being called every time, so it might not be an ideal choice.

### Method 2 - Only first call on group, several methods

If what you really need is for only the first call of `observeEventType` to use the group, then one option is to have two versions of `myFirebaseFunction`: one much like the one you already have and one using `observeSingleEventOfType`. Then load stuff could call both of those functions, only passing `dispatch_group_leave` as a completion to one of them:

```
func loadStuff() {
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
        myInitialFirebaseFunction() {
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
        }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("done")
    }

    myFirebaseFunction({})
}

func myInitialFirebaseFunction(completionHandler: () -> ()) {

    let usersRef = firebase.child("likes")
    usersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        processSnapshot(snapshot)
        completionHandler()
    })   
}

func myFirebaseFunction(completionHandler: () -> ()) {

    let usersRef = firebase.child("likes")
    usersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        processSnapshot(snapshot)
        completionHandler()
    })   
}

func processSnapshot(snapshot: FDataSnapshot) {

    if snapshot.exists() {
        let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date",ascending: false)])

        for item in sorted {
            dict.append(item as! NSDictionary)
        }
    }
}
```

### Method 3 - Only first call on group, no extra methods

Note that because `loadStuff` in "Method 2" basically loads things from Firebase twice, it might not be as efficient as you'd like. In that case you could instead use a `Bool` to determine whether leave should be called:

```
var shouldLeaveGroupOnProcess = false

func loadStuff() {
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
        shouldLeaveGroupOnProcess = true
        myFirebaseFunction() {
            if shouldLeaveGroupOnProcess {
                shouldLeaveGroupOnProcess = false
                dispatch_group_leave(group)
            }
        }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("done")
    }
}

func myFirebaseFunction(completionHandler: () -> ()) {

    let usersRef = firebase.child("likes")
    usersRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.exists() {
            let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date",ascending: false)])

            for item in sorted {
                dict.append(item as! NSDictionary)
            }
        }
        completionHandler()
    })   
}
```

Here, even if multiple calls to `observeEventType` are made during the initial load, `leave` is guaranteed to be called only once and no crashed should occur.

### Swift 3

> PS Currently I'm using Swift 2.3, but an upgrade to Swift 3 is planned, so it would be very awesome to receive an answer capable for both.

Dispatch has gotten a complete overhaul in Swift 3 (it is object-oriented), so code that works well on both is not really a thing :)

But the concepts of each of the three methods above are the same. In Swift 3:

- Create your group with one of the inits of `DispatchGroup`
- `dispatch_group_enter` is now the instance method `enter` on the group
- `dispatch_group_leave` is now the instance method `leave` on the group
- `dispatch_group_notify` is now the instance method `notify` on the group

Comment: holy crap. thank you very much for all the effort and time you've put into your answer. will check it asap

Comment: @DavidSeek Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var group : dispatch_group_t?
```

// in your init function.. OR ... in your viewDidLoad

```
group = dispatch_group_create()
```

//add functions

```
func leaveDispatchGroup(){
     dispatch_group_leave(group!)
}

func joinDispatchGroup(){
     dispatch_group_enter(group!)
}
```

// perform your operations

```
func makeAllAPICalls() {

    self.joinDispatchGroup()
    //API Operation

    self.myFirebaseFunction() {
        //leave group on completion
        self.leaveDispatchGroup()
    }

    self.joinDispatchGroup()
    //API Operation
    self.newFirebasedFunction() {

        //leave group on completion
        self.leaveDispatchGroup()
    }


    //this will call once your all operation will leave the group, so add this after join all operations
    dispatch_group_notify(group!, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        //dispatch group notify...
        print("done")
    }
}
```

//your functions

```
func myFirebaseFunction(completionHandler: () -> ()) {
     completionHandler()  
}

func newFirebasedFunction(completionHandler: () -> ()){
     completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: and how is this different from my logic? it will crash once the observer receives stuff and the function will be called again, because there is no dispatch join, but a leave or not?