# Dispatch Group not working for completion block

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

Trying to get return reply objects from a network call. The session is a class that is using the star scream API. I just can't seem to get this to work. It's only printing out 1 set of results which is the from the first id. What am I missing here?

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

for i in 0 ..< marketIds.count {
    myGroup.enter()
    self.session.retrieve(withMethod: MarketKeys.key, withParameters: [MarketKeys.id: marketIds[i]], completion: { (results, error) in
        print("results \n")
        print(results!)
        myGroup.leave()
        })
    }
myGroup.notify(queue:.main) {
print("Done")
}
```

Comment: I think you should review `NSOperation` for this

Comment: @ReinierMelian actually, it is *not* necessary, he is missing the notifying part... Anyway, I would add a related question.

Comment: You are missing the "notifying" part. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41809248/5501940

Comment: what does session.retreive do?

Comment: I would start by making sure that `marketIds.count` is actually greater than 1. Add a print statement after the call to `enter` and make sure you're looping as much as you think you are. (Side note, this should be `for id in marketIds` rather than using subscripting. Subscripting works, but it creates more oppotunities for your app to crash. But this has nothing to do with your problem.)

Comment: I know I was just using the "i" to print the count of the for loop to check

Answer (score 5):

This [article](http://jordansmith.io/dispatch-groups-in-swift-3/) gives you a quick reference guide to simple `DispatchGroup` use.

An example:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

dispatchGroup.enter()
longRunningFunction { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.enter()
longRunningFunctionTwo { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Both functions complete ")
}
```

The notify function is called when all items in the queue have been processed and allows you to react to this accordingly. So the example above will run two long running tasks and then will output "Both functions complete "

Answer (score 0):

Add this so notification to group can be sent

```
 myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
   print("Both functions complete ")
  }
```

Comment: Add this where?

Comment: outside the for loop

Comment: So notifying isn't the issue. The problem is that "session retrieve" only gets executed once. When in fact it could be getting called 3 times or the count of "marketIds"