# How can I do things when two asynchronous requests are finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I do things when two asynchronous requests are finished ?

perform the asynchronous `initRequest` and asynchronous `refreshHeader`, they finished after I perform the `requestEnd` method.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initRequest];
    [self requestEnd];
}

- (void)initRequest{
    [GBCompanyRequest requestWithSuccess:^(EvaluationAverage *evaluationAverage) {

    } failure:^(NSString *message) {

    }];

    [self refreshHeader];
}

- (void)refreshHeader{
    [GBCompanyEvaluationRequest requestWithSuccess:^(EvaluationAverage *evaluationAverage) {

    } failure:^(NSString *message) {

    }];
}

- (void)requestEnd{
    NSLog(@"How can I do things when two asynchronous requests are finished");
}

@end
```

Comment: Search for "dispatch_group" or "completion handler".

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is use [`dispatch_group_t`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatch_group_t)

**dispatch_group_t** : Generally use for call/execute group of  synchronously or asynchronously method/block and it will notify you after all the method/block execution are done.

For more information about how to use, you can read this Q/A.

[Waiting until two async blocks are executed before starting another block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909629/waiting-until-two-async-blocks-are-executed-before-starting-another-block#20910658)

Comment: But asynchronous request in the other method. I do not know how to use the dispatch_group_t to do it.

Comment: That's I added 2 links so you can read and add it to your app