# How we identify that when we use NSThread,GCD or Operation Queues when our app is unresponsive?

Tags: ios, multithreading

1. I have some R&D on Google and find out some facts and figure but I am unable to understand.
2. Basically i want why we use most GCD as compare to `NSThread` for smaller tasks.

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653522/grand-central-dispatch-vs-nsthread

Comment: 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238135/grand-central-dispatch-vs-nsthreads?rq=1